# Reputation enough to comment or vote but Stack Overflow doesn't think so?

Tags: support, reputation, login

I have found some odd behavior on the stackoverflow.com site. I was logged in as me on stackoverflow (which apparently is a "different me" than my id on meta.stackoverflow.com (although the email addresses clearly match!). On the stackoverflow site I have 26 reputation points, one teacher badge and some other random upvoates. I was trying to bring some current state of affairs truth to the following question on the regular stackoverflow site (logged in with my usual stackoverflow account) [Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements) but it told me I couldn't comment because I didn't have at least 10 reputation points.

Perhaps my reputation points are being read off of my "meta.stackoverflow.com" login yet stackoverflow.com shows the points I have accrued through participation in that site?

Help?
Thanks
Steve

Comment: Doth thou have a screenshot?

Comment: You need 50 rep to comment on SO

Comment: And on meta you can comment with 1 rep. On the main site you need 50.

Comment: @Knights who say Ni: rather than screen shot, just follow link to my profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/1510640/stephan-doliov

Comment: @Bart if you following the link to the question that I was trying to provide some factual update to, you will see that immediately below the question is a div that says ..."protected by Community...you must have at least 10 reputation points" I hope this helps. Maybe the at least 10 reputation points blurb should be updated to state 50 if that is the case?

Comment: Well its written 10 rep needed to answer (but its still 50 for comments)

Comment: and to the stack overflow team, I appreciate the value of trying to keep newbie spam off of the site, that's great! In the case of the question I stumbled across, the answers and comments are false and in this case my not being able to update it with factual pointers is not doing anyone a favor. :( I would think that if I earned a teacher badge by diving deep into Apache source code to help solve someone's problem I might have the credibility to set the record straight elsewhere too.

Comment: @StephanDoliov It says *"**To answer it**, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site."* Comments are not answers, and answers are not comments.

Answer (score 1):

[Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and Stack [Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) are different sites, with different IDs. As well as different reputation counters. You have 1 reputation here (at the moment), and 26 reputation on the main site.

I have 11,124 reputation here, and 41,332 on the main site. This is by-design.

---

In any case you need 50 reputation points to earn the "[Comment Everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)" privilege on Stack Oveflow

Comment: can the language on the div on the stack overflow site be corrected so that it would read to reflect the state of affairs? If the language had said one needs at least 50 points, then I would not even have started this thread. :)

Comment: @StephanDoliov: It would really help if you attach a screenshot (or a link of a screenshot) to your original question. I've tagged your question as [meta-tag:bug] for now.

Comment: @StephanDoliov No, it states you need 10 rep to answer. Not comment.

Comment: Thanks Madara, @Bart is correct. The tag says one needs 10 reputation points to answer. The tag doesn't say anything regard how many points are needed to comment. My fault for thinking that answering and commenting were identical activities. So it's technically not a bug. Perhaps it's a feature or perhaps it ought to be a feature request that such auto generated divs clearly enumerate that answering requires 10 feature points whereas commenting requires 50 feature points. :)  Best to all.

Comment: @StephanDoliov The thing is that commenting always take 50 rep whereas answering normally takes 0.